# How do I force a particular bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am writing a paper for a journal that enforces the use of the Springer '[splncs03.bst](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/splncs03.bst)' file for references. I wrote most of the paper with `natbib` and the use of the `\citep` and `\citet` commands so it would be really hard to go back to the default LaTeX citation system.

The first problem was that the template file was completely incompatible with natbib but I found a fix [here](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/natbib-compatible-bibtex-style-bst-file.html). The problem with this fix, however, is that the bibliography is printed out in the completely wrong style. The author of the fix suggests that you can change the heading of the bibliography to 'References' by adding `\renewcommand\bibname{References}` but this does not fix the style. I'm pretty sure I just need to force Latex to use the default article bibliography style.

Here is an an example of the styles, I'm getting the style on the left, I want the style on the right. Notice the font size, numbering and title are all different.

[image: An example of the bibliography styles.]

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: IMHO Well, if the journal enforces some style and they do not support `natbib`'s features, it is their decision. I suppose the reason is to enforce the `\cite` commands to always show the bracket number. Still, asking the journal editor for a solution cannot harm, but I suppose he'll tell you: "You have the style, nothing else's allowed."

Comment: I'll have to submit the tex and bib files I assume. If I can't use natbib is there anyway I can print the author of a citation or will I have to go through and manually type in each authors name where needed? Maybe I should rewrite the style of the paper to not use author's names  when referencing at all.

Comment: The second paragraph of the `.bst` file you linked states: "Use `\documentclass{llncs}` and `\bibliographystyle{splncs03}`, and cite a reference with (e.g.) `\cite{smith77}` to get a "[1]" in the text." This shouldn't make it fundamentally incompatible with `natbib`. Just be sure to (i) issue the command `\setcitestyle{numbers,square}` after loading the `natbib` package and (ii) use the command `\citep` to generate "purely numeric" citations, of the form "`[2]`". (`\citet` will generate citations of the form "`Jones [2]`", which probably goes against the journal's citation style.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the journal enforces some style and they do not support `natbib`'s features, it is their decision. I suppose the reason is to enforce the `\cite` commands to always show the bracket number.

Still, asking the journal editor for a solution cannot harm, but I suppose he'll tell you: "You have the style, nothing else's allowed."

As well, be quite sure that the editors will be angry if you start messing their style without them seeing any good reason for doing so.

*(I'm a graphic editor of one journal, too, so I bring some experience here.)*